# User.IsInRole always returns false with Token Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I have ASP.NET Core 2 configured to use JWT Tokens to authenticate. The configuration looks like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:Key"]))
        };
    });
```

Then I created a method where a user signs in which looks like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("token")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Token([FromBody] LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest("Could not create token");

    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);

    if (user == null) return BadRequest("Could not create token");
    var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, false);
    if (!result.Succeeded) return BadRequest("Could not create token");
    var claims = new[]
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
    };

    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Tokens:Key"]));
    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
        _configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
        claims,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
        signingCredentials: creds);

    return Ok(new {
        access_token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
        roles });
}
```

}

I save the token and use it in my request. I have a very simple api endpoint:

```
[HttpGet("users")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public IActionResult GetUsers()
{
    var isInRole = HttpContext.User.IsInRole(Roles.Administrator);
    return Ok(_service.GetAllUsers());
}
```

Here I get in the method, but `isInRole` is always false. Even though my `var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);` returns a list of roles including Administrator. Why does this not work then?

Comment: You are returning the token as access_token without any role information. The roles are passed as an additional element. Shouldn't you add the roles to the claims so they are added to the token? Otherwise how are you passing the roles to your GetUsers call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the Role claim into your `claims` array like so

```
var claims = new[]
{
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
    //role claim
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator")
};
```

This is what Asp.Net will look at in the `[Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]` attribute and `HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Administrator");`

Similarly `ClaimTypes.Name` is used to produce `User.Identity.Name` in your controller

I suggest you read the excellent article by Rui Figueiredo [Secure a Web Api in ASP.NET Core](http://www.blinkingcaret.com/2017/09/06/secure-web-api-in-asp-net-core/) on the subject

Comment: I have added both but it still returns false for IsInRole("Administrator")

Comment: Nvm it actually did work. I had a mixup in my code. Thanks!

Comment: @us This is a working code. 

Please check array insted of append use list to compse it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<string> GenerateEncodedToken(string userName, string email, List<string> roles, ClaimsIdentity identity)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, userName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, email),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, await _jwtOptions.JtiGenerator()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, ToUnixEpochDate(_jwtOptions.IssuedAt).ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64)
            };

            var id = identity.FindFirst(Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Id);
            claims.Add(id);

            roles.ForEach(role =>
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
            });


            var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _jwtOptions.Issuer,
                audience: _jwtOptions.Audience,
                claims: claims,
                notBefore: _jwtOptions.NotBefore,
                expires: _jwtOptions.Expiration,
                signingCredentials: _jwtOptions.SigningCredentials);

            var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

            return encodedJwt;
        }
```